# Does anyone know the author or name of the book described? It is about a world in stasis

Tags: story-identification

A bottle is tossed back and forth over a bonfire and the female ends up in a world that is in stasis - continuous good weather in one half, continuous gloomy drizzle in the other;  for every birth within each half there must be a death; people cannot travel from one half to the other.  Her arrival upsets the balance.